# Gatling reuse session in open loop

Tags: load-testing, gatling

For a load test I have the following scenario:

- Login
- MainPage1

  - Page1
- MainPage2

  - Page2
  - Page3
  - Page4
- MainPage3

  - Page5
  - Page6

The login is performed against a web application firewall (WAF), using a login form with some dynamic values.

I have to model an open loop, so I need a constant rate of requests/s or users/s. The problem is, I can not constantly inject new users, as the login step is effectively throttled by the WAF that blocks requests if the rate is too high.

So I need to create a session cookie only once for each user and reuse the cookies for the rest of the load test.

I used this scenario:

```
val users = ...
val rampup = ...
val duration = ...

var login = exec(_.set("username", username).set("password", password))
    .exec(WAF.login)
    .exec(flushHttpCache)

val scn1 = scenario("Scenario 1")
    .exec(login) // only once for each user
    .during(duration seconds) { //repeat for the rest of the test
      group("Page"){
        exec(Pages.mainPage1)
         .exec(Pages.mainPage2)
         .exec(Pages.mainPage3)
     }
  }

setUp(
  scn1.inject(rampUsers(users) over(rampup seconds))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

But this modelled a closed loop, with each iteration of the "Page" group being throttled by the response times of the SuT.
I tried to `.throttle` the scenario, but this creates an upper boundary, no lower.

I cannot use `constantUsersPerSec` as this would create a new user for each iteration, which is effectively blocked by the WAF.

Are there any alternatives to setup and reuse the sessions before the actual test scenario? Or otherwise setup a constant rate test?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - not because of the login rate blockade, but because we wanted to test end-points of different microservices without perf testing login microservice within these simulations (they are tested in separate simulations/pipelines).

I wanted to login just once per each perf test, which usually lasts for 30-60 sec and it injects hundreds or thousands of users. I don't know if this approach is suitable for you but in our case I needed to pass just cookies, generated within the login process.

So, I've extracted cookies gathered through the login Htpp POST request, using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html):

```
def getLoginCookies() : Array[Header] = {
  val nameValuePairs = new util.ArrayList[NameValuePair](10)
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", loginUsername))
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginPassword))

  val response = getHttpPostResponse(baseUrl + loginUrl, nameValuePairs)

  val cookies = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")
  response.close()
  cookies
}

private def getHttpPostResponse(url: String, nameValuePairs: util.ArrayList[NameValuePair]) : CloseableHttpResponse = {
  val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
  val post = new HttpPost(url)
  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))
  val response = client.execute(post)
  client.close()
  response
}
```

In the scenario object, I'm collecting all cookie values:

```
private val cookies = getLoginCookies()

private var cookieValue = ""
for (cookie <- cookies) {
  cookieValue += cookie.getValue + ";"
}
```

...and I specify the header for the consequent Http GET requests in my scenario e.g.:

```
  private lazy val homepage =
    exec(http(name)
     .get(url)
     .header(HttpHeaderNames.Cookie, cookieValue)
     .disableFollowRedirect
     .check(status.is(200)))
```

Hope that helps or at least gives a hint.